NFS3 mount (ro, no_root_squash) OR rw for non-root user of same folder on same client?
I'm wondering whether it's possible to have a client where root can get read-only access to an entire NFS3 export on a server, and other users can get read-write access to files they are authorized to access?
I think this amounts to asking whether entries in /etc/exports on the server are processed up to first-match or first-success.
Consider server /etc/exports
/home/foo   192.168.0.100(ro,no_root_squash) 192.168.0.0/24(rw)

And on 192.168.0.100 automount for user foo attempts to mount his home. Does this "succeed" but give read-only, or fail because the mount request isn't read-only (both first-match), or move on to the second entry in /etc/exports and succeed properly? Is the  behaviour defined in any documentation?
Also would it work to create a bind mount of the same folder on the server and export that for root to get read-only access through a different entry in /etc/exports, while for any other user automount works as normal?
(Yes, I know NFS3 is woefully insecure anyway! )


And on 192.168.0.100 automount for user foo attempts to mount his home. Does this "succeed" but give read-only, or fail because the mount request isn't read-only (both first-match),

The mount will succeed because the NFSv3 'MOUNT' protocol does not have "read-only" or "read-write" mount requests. The client only requests a fhandle for a specific export path and that's it – it doesn't know whether the export is read-only until it actually attempts some kind of write operation and gets a NFSERR_ROFS in return.
Also, for that matter, NFS mounts always use root's credentials; especially automounts, as the autofs daemon is running as root. Again, user access is checked individually for each operation – the server does not remember any state about which user mounted what; there's only a single mount per client host, instead each individual NFS request (read/write/etc) includes the UID+GID of whoever was responsible.
I have doubts about bind mounts being able to differentiate; the thing about the NFS server is that it traditionally does not operate on paths but on 'file handles' which perform a slightly lower-level access to the filesystem. And a given file will always have the same fhandle no matter which bind mound it is accessed through.

Also, it's not "first-match" in this situation. The exports(5) manual page of the file format says:
   NFS clients may be specified in a number of ways:

   single host [...]
   IP networks [...]
   wildcards [...]
   netgroups [...]
   anonymous [...]

   If a client matches more than one of the specifications above, then the  first  match  from  the
   above list order takes precedence - regardless of the order they appear on the export line. How‐
   ever,  if a client matches more than one of the same type of specification (e.g. two netgroups),
   then the first match from the order they appear on the export line takes precedence.

Meaning that a 192.168.0.100 "single host" entry will take priority over a /24 entry regardless of its position in the list.
